# My blockquote isn't running. I have link the bootstrap css and js files too but it doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4

I have linked the downloaded css and js files from bootstrap but the features don't seem to work as it should. The `<blockquote>` tag is just returning simple text. Also the `<cite> </cite>` isn't giving me "-". What seems to be the issue ?

```html
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Cheat Sheet</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Block Quotes -->

  <blockquote class="blockquote">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>
    <footer>Quote By <cite title="John Doe">John Doe</cite></footer>
  </blockquote>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that you have correctly loaded the `bootstrap.css` file (you can check console in the developer tools)... and your `custom.css` is not overriding the `blockquote` class...

The **snippet below** should work for you:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">

  <blockquote class="blockquote">
    <p>For 50 years, WWF has been protecting the future of nature. The world's leading conservation organization, WWF works in 100 countries and is supported by 1.2 million members in the United States and close to 5 million globally.</p>
    <footer class="blockquote-footer">From WWF's website</footer>
  </blockquote>

  <blockquote class="blockquote">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>
    <footer>Quote By <cite title="John Doe">John Doe</cite></footer>
  </blockquote>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes I figured, it should be <footer class = "blockquote-footer"> now on Bootstrap 4. Fixed. Thanks !